# Freescale ARM mcu

Tags: freescale

I'm looking to go for a freescale arm cortex m0, specifically for MKE04Z8VTG4 device. The question is: it is possible to programming it from uart? Without any hardware programmer? Is there some ide for c language programming?

Comment: Insuffient research - question should be closed.

Comment: @LeonHeller wrong as usual. You would think manufacturers would make such things like bootloaders quite prominent in their data sheets, **but in fact they usually do not**.  Typically it buried in some other family series app note.  And for a **missing feature** (which is my strong suspicion for freescale ARMs) there is usually *nothing* which says it doesn't exist - only an inability to find anything which says it does.  SWD should work though, and you can use another similar part like one of the USB-capable Freedom boards as a programmer with openOCD.

Comment: Plenty of information is readily available. Question should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, STM is providing their chips with a UART Bootloader. With them you just connect your USB-UART Module to the UART1-Pins and pull Boot0 and Boot1 High.

But mostly for ARM Cortex Stuff you can use any SWD Programmer available. Cheap one start on ebay for around 5$. STLink is just STM's Branding for their SWD.

[Freescale offers you a list of IDE's you can use](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/overview.jsp?code=KINETIS_IDES), of which many use C to programm